# Would questions regarding which file sharing sites exist for chemical files in particular be appropriate for Chem SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a question about which file-sharing websites exist that are specifically designed for chemical file formats (e.g., .mol, .pdb, .sdf, .xyz, *etc.*). Would such a question be appropriate for this website or would it be labelled as off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for this SE?

Answer (score 5):

I think that's definitely a question of interest for the chemistry community. Databases (open or closed), amongst other online resources, are key in certains areas of chemistry, including crystallography, cheminformatics, etc.